# how to make small chunks of python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pytorch

hi i have python sub dictionary  like this

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
dic = {
  "A": [0.2822, -0.0958, -0.5165, -0.3812, 
        -0.3469,  0.4025, -0.0696, -0.1246,
        -0.1132,  0.4170, -0.0383, -0.4071, 
        -0.5407,  0.1519,  0.5630,  0.1276],
  "B": [1.0014, 0.9980, 1.0012, 0.9986, 
       1.0001, 0.9999, 1.0016, 1.0014, 
       1.0008, 0.9996, 1.0008, 1.0004, 
       1.0000, 0.9987, 0.9997, 0.9989]
}
```

for key 1 i have 16 values, i want to make 2 chunks of size 8 for key A.  how it can be possible?

Like first 8 values stored in separate array and last 8 values stoed ins eparate array or dictionary with their key values.
as shown in this image
[image]

Comment: It is unclear if you want to only process A and not B or all and if you want to keep the original keys, or not. Please provide the full expected output as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd refer to keys as what they are (i.e. Key 'A' has 16 values, not key 1). It's a good practice to just think of dictionaries as unordered and simply a group of key-value pairs.

Second, using numpy will allow us to split the key we want into two (or more) even groups. If you end up needing to split a list of 30 elements into three lists, this code will still work.

```py
import numpy as np

dic = {
  "A": [0.2822, -0.0958, -0.5165, -0.3812,
        -0.3469,  0.4025, -0.0696, -0.1246,
        -0.1132,  0.4170, -0.0383, -0.4071,
        -0.5407,  0.1519,  0.5630,  0.1276],
  "B": [1.0014, 0.9980, 1.0012, 0.9986,
       1.0001, 0.9999, 1.0016, 1.0014,
       1.0008, 0.9996, 1.0008, 1.0004,
       1.0000, 0.9987, 0.9997, 0.9989]
}

# We give array_split() our list, and how many we want it split into.
a1, a2 = np.array_split(dic['A'], 2) # We get our two lists returned.
dic['A1'] = a1.tolist() # Numpy returns it as an np.array, so let's put it back into a list.
dic['A2'] = a2.tolist()
del(dic['A']) # Remove the now unused key-value.
```

```
{'B': [1.0014, 0.998, 1.0012, 0.9986, 1.0001, 0.9999, 1.0016, 1.0014, 1.0008, 0.9996, 1.0008, 1.0004, 1.0, 0.9987, 0.9997, 0.9989],
 'A1': [0.2822, -0.0958, -0.5165, -0.3812, -0.3469, 0.4025, -0.0696, -0.1246],
 'A2': [-0.1132, 0.417, -0.0383, -0.4071, -0.5407, 0.1519, 0.563, 0.1276]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```py
for key in dic:
    dic[key + "1"] = dic[key][:8] # Create A1 (or B1)
    dic[key + "2"] = dic[key][8:] # Create A2 (or B2)
    del dic[key] # Remove A (or B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this sorta like what you're looking for?

```
>>> dic["A1"]=dic["A"][:8]
>>> dic["A2"]=dic["A"][8:]
>>> dic["A2"]
[-0.1132, 0.417, -0.0383, -0.4071, -0.5407, 0.1519, 0.563, 0.1276]
>>> dic["A1"]
[0.2822, -0.0958, -0.5165, -0.3812, -0.3469, 0.4025, -0.0696, -0.1246]
>>> dic
{'A': [0.2822, -0.0958, -0.5165, -0.3812, -0.3469, 0.4025, -0.0696, -0.1246, -0.1132, 0.417, -0.0383, -0.4071, -0.5407, 0.1519, 0.563, 0.1276], 'B': [1.0014, 0.998, 1.0012, 0.9986, 1.0001, 0.9999, 1.0016, 1.0014, 1.0008, 0.9996, 1.0008, 1.0004, 1.0, 0.9987, 0.9997, 0.9989], 'A1': [0.2822, -0.0958, -0.5165, -0.3812, -0.3469, 0.4025, -0.0696, -0.1246], 'A2': [-0.1132, 0.417, -0.0383, -0.4071, -0.5407, 0.1519, 0.563, 0.1276]}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dictionary by slicing each list in half for two new keys:

```
from collections import ChainMap

d = {
  'a': [0.2822, -0.0958, -0.5165, -0.3812, 
        -0.3469,  0.4025, -0.0696, -0.1246,
        -0.1132,  0.4170, -0.0383, -0.4071, 
        -0.5407,  0.1519,  0.5630,  0.1276],
  'b': [1.0014, 0.9980, 1.0012, 0.9986, 
        1.0001, 0.9999, 1.0016, 1.0014, 
        1.0008, 0.9996, 1.0008, 1.0004, 
        1.0000, 0.9987, 0.9997, 0.9989]
}

new_d = dict(ChainMap(
    *[{f'{k}1': v[:len(v)//2], f'{k}2': v[len(v)//2:]} for k, v in d.items()]
))
print(new_d)
```